# ApexChart update series and labels

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I create a ApexChart with empty values because I dynamically add series and labels.

```
var options777 = {
    chart: {
        height: 397,
        type: 'line',
        toolbar: {
            show: false,
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Elegibility',
        type: 'column',
        data: []
    }],
    stroke: {
        width: [0, 4]
    },
    // labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    labels: [],
    xaxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yaxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'Elegibility',
        }
    }
};

var chart777 = new ApexCharts(
    document.querySelector("#elegibilityChart"),
    options777
);
if (document.getElementById('elegibilityChart')) {
    chart777.render();
}
```

Then, I have a function that receives two arrays, one with the series data and other with label data. The arrays are same size, series contains numbers and labels strings.

```
function setData(mySeries, myLabels) {  
    chart777.updateOptions({
        series: {
            data: mySeries
        },
        labels: myLabels
    })      
}
```

When I run my code, it returns: `error TypeError: "options$$1.series[0] is undefined"`

How can I update the series and labels in the ApexChart?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you're updating both the series and the labels, this will need to be done in two separate calls.

Use the [updateSeries](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#updateSeries) method to provide the new data series (as an array).

Use the [updateOptions](https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#updateOptions) method to provide the new labels (as an object that will merge with the existing options, keeping any configurations not overridden).

Answer (score 3):

```js
chart1.updateOptions({
   xaxis: {
      categories: year
   },
   series: [{
      data: trend
   }],
});
```

You should use code like this, I mean you should update xaxis categories instead of labels and also comment labels in options and instead use xaxis categories.

Comment: thank you after some many methods and so many trails, this methos is working like charm.